# How can I test API calls in postman in the .net core 2.1 Angular template?

Tags: api, postman, asp.net-core-2.1

I can't seem to connect to any of my controller methods in Postman. It does work in the angular app. The project is generated as the doc suggets [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

This controller method comes with the template:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
{
    private static string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            DateFormatted = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index).ToString("d"),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        });
    }

    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public string DateFormatted { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF
        {
            get
            {
                return 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs I have configured the routes as follows:

```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //delay timeout 2 min to avoid timeout
                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

When I run the application and try to make a get request in Postman I get no response. I'm calling:

https://localhost:44389/api/sampledata/weatherforecasts

I figured it may be a port problem but this is the port the application runs on but I could be missing something

Any ideas?

Comment: If you go to that URL from your browser, do you see the expected results?

Comment: When you say no response, your not getting a status code back? like 500 or 404? One thing that gets me sometimes is you need to make sure its a GET not a POST

Comment: @SiKing yes I do apparently!

Comment: @bgraham No status code - "There was an error connectiong to <endpoint>. I am sure I am making a GET in postman

Comment: @SiKing any ideas how I get it to work in postman?

Comment: Maybe try to recreate the Postman collection? If in a browser you can see the expected result, and I assume you already checked your server logs for any information, then it must be a problem with your Postman setup. However, you did not provide any information about that setup, so I can only speculate.

Comment: It worked ok for me with that url, chaning the port. You may need to go in to postmans settings and turn off SSL certificate validation, as Visual Studio creates a certificate so that you can use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
In **Startup.cs** let's **comment** or **delete** this line.

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Then Postman acts as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with .Net Core 3.1 Angular template, but it is worked to me if I remove api from url.

Eg: https://localhost:44389/sampledata/weatherforecasts